# Codeigniter - Query result multiple table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

So I would have four tables

title (table)

- id
- title_name
- id_director [fk director.id_director]

director (table)

- id_director
- director_name

actor (table)

- id_actor
- actor_name

title_actor (table)

- id
- id_title [fk title.id]
- id_actor [fk actor.id_actor]

My Controler (for that I decided not to use Model)

```
public function list_title_detalis($id)
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('title a');
$this->db->join('director', 'director.id_director = a.id_director');
$this->db->join('title_actor', 'title_actor.id_title = a.id');
$this->db->join('actor b', 'b.id_actor= title_actor.id_actor'); 
$this->db->where('a.id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['iten'] = $query->result();
$this->load->view('title_detail_view', $data);
```

My view

```
    foreach ($iten as $title){
echo '<p>'.($title->title_name).'</p>';
echo "<a href='" . base_url() .'directors/detail/' . $title->id_director. "'>";
echo '<p>'.($title->name_director).'</p>'; // It's correct!!!
echo "<a href='" . base_url() .'actors/detail/' . $title->id_actor. "'>";
echo '<p>'.($title->name_actor).'</p>';
```

}

Is it like that?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening? Edit: Sorry, I see the comments now (but it'd be helpful if you stated the problem in the question text too)

Comment: Yes. Normalize your design

Comment: Please explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the design of these tables - instead of having a bunch of columns named id_actor(x), you should add a new table that joins titles to actors.  This is called a junction table, and it solves the problem of many-to-many relationships.

The table is simple - it just has three columns (id, id_title, and id_actor).  This structure will allow you to have titles with anywhere from zero to an infinite number of actors.

Comment: Ok Chris, I edited my question. Can you check for correctness?

Comment: Chris, your sugestion  works. Thank you very much. How do I vote in your answer?